# Running multiple docker containers in the same environment

Tags: docker

Can't seem to connect API running on my localhost with webapp that's running as well on another local host. Note they are containerized on 2 different containers. API calls don't seem to get endpoints on my application.
What's the way to run them both in the same environment?

I've used maven to create a .jar of my app and did docker build and docker run on specified port on localhost. Currently searching how to run docker-compose of these two so that endpoints can be reached. (note API is on port:1026 and app on port:1028)
Any ideas?

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve]?  What URLs are you trying to call, in what sort of network environment, and what results do you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dockerfile needs to be configured and common net service created for the application as well as the services. Then the whole stack works with compose-up if they are listed on the same network.